# Make udisks2 clean up stale mount points?

Tags: linux, arch-linux, mount, udisks

`udisks2` with `udiskie` are set up to automount USB storage devices. Connecting a pen drive labeled `MYDRIVE`, it is mounted to:

```
/media/MYDRIVE
```

When pulling the drive without prior unmounting, the above directory persists.

*Is it possible to get stale mount points be deleted right away?*

I've actually seen that happening in an several years old installation of Ubuntu. So it is possible, though perhaps not with `udisks2`: I don't know what software for managing removable media is part of that installation.

**Update:** Raised the issue [on GitHub](https://github.com/coldfix/udiskie/issues/63).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The maintainer of `udiskie` [pointed out](https://github.com/coldfix/udiskie/issues/63#issuecomment-95943089) that stale mount points not being cleaned up is a [bug in `udisks2`](https://bugs.freedesktop.org/show_bug.cgi?id=90174). In fact, after more tests, I can confirm that sometimes the mount point *is* deleted.