# udisks2 doesn't clean up mount points on shutdown

Tags: arch-linux, udisks

If I shut down my computer while a device that was mounted by udisks is still mounted, the folder where it was mounted still remains.
If I then mount that device again later, a '1' will be appended to the name (or higher numbers if the lower numbers are taken).

The owner of these empty folders is root; owner has rwx permissions, the rest has none.

I'm running Arch Linux with xfce4 as desktop manager.
My udisks version is 2.1.7-1

I configured udisks to mount the devices in /media using these instructions: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Udisks#Mount_to_.2Fmedia_.28udisks2.29

Is there anything I can do to fix this so the folders will be removed on shutdown?

My problem is similar to this problem, with the difference being in which situation it occurs:
[Make udisks2 clean up stale mount points?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/198018/make-udisks2-clean-up-stale-mount-points)
. This appered to be a bug in udisks (solved by now). Should I report my situation as a bug too?

Edit:
This only applies to shared mounts.
If I remove the rule that makes mounts shared by default the cleaning up is done properly.

Answer (score 0):

I found this mentioned in a [Github issue](https://github.com/coldfix/udiskie/issues/104); they suggest mounting `/media` as a tmpfs so it will be cleaned up on restart. In `/etc/fstab`:

```
tmpfs /media tmpfs nodev,nosuid,size=1M 0 0
```

Comment: But  from reading the udisks2 Arch Wiki it should not be necessary to mount /media as a tmpfs OR to place a script in /etc/tmpfiles.d to do the same thing. From my testing plug in and out ONE USB key and the mount point directory IS removed, but if I plug in two or more USB keys and then plug out one of them that mount point dir is not removed.